# How do I use sql scripts to retrieve these guids

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server filestream storage, I find these guids in my Windows SQL Server folder. I don't know if they can be obtained by using SQL scripts.

Where are these guids coming from ?

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from using links to explain problems. Wise professionals avoid unknown links and is there a reason you cannot show the picture in the post, at least?

Comment: I see you solved that problem. Cool. Much better. You can format the link like this:
 `[Web-Page-Name](Actual-Link-Address)` as in [Google-Search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: No ahmed did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can. There are multiple ways of accomplishing this, from simple, specific CLR applications to the **undocumented stored procedures** Microsoft has included.

> DISCLAIMER: The following procs are limited to permissions that the
>   account SQL Server Agent runs under.

### **xp_dirtree - undocumented**

Returns a tabular result set from the directory path. Second parameter sets the depth of subdirectories to traverse (0 means return all subdirectories). Third parameter is BIT that decides whether to include files in result set.

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree '<directory_path>', 0, 1
```

[image: master.sys.xp_dirtree]

### **xp_fileexist -undocumented**

Great for checking single locations pre-steps before inserting files in a script.

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_fileexist 'C:\FilesCompare_SQL Files\FilesCompare.txt'
```

[image: master.sys.xp_fileexist]